# How to populate OptionMenu in tkinter with parameters?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

Currently I have made a basic template of drop down menu using tkinter which has three parameters one,two,three.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar()
variable.set("one") # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

[image]

See above image for more clarity.

Now I have dictionary with 30 key-value pairs how can I populate them as options in OptionMenu.
Dictionary:

```
"Belgium (Dutch)": "nl_be",
                 "Hungary": "hu_hu",
                 "Chile": "es_cl",
                 "Belgium (French)": "fr_be",
                 "Mexico": "es_mx",
                 "Hong Kong": "hk",
                 "Turkey": "tr_tr",
                 "Ireland": "en_ie",
                 "Ghana": "en_gh",
                 "Argentina": "es_ar",
                 "Slovakia": "sk_sk",
```

I just want the keys of dictionary as options in optionmenu.
Instead of passing each key of dictionary in OptionMenu() is their any smart technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `*` to unpack list into many arguments

```
OptionMenu(master, variable, *data.keys())
```

Full

```
data = {
"Belgium (Dutch)": "nl_be",
 "Hungary": "hu_hu",
 "Chile": "es_cl",
 "Belgium (French)": "fr_be",
 "Mexico": "es_mx",
 "Hong Kong": "hk",
 "Turkey": "tr_tr",
 "Ireland": "en_ie",
 "Ghana": "en_gh",
 "Argentina": "es_ar",
 "Slovakia": "sk_sk",
}

from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar()
variable.set("one") # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *data.keys())
w.pack()

mainloop()
```